# Surprise itself is inferior to me

Tags: riddle

> I am the Apple of this very country.
>
> Some sort of politeness we will all share, will we?
>
> Surprise itself is inferior to me.
>
> But for you, today, I am mostly irony.

What I am ?

An hint :

> Threaten me with your invisible bow and all my secrets I will reveal.

Comment: I edited my answer, I'm very curious to know if I'm getting closer to the intended solution

Answer (score 2):

I think I'm getting closer, but maybe not quite there. Are you...

> The reputation gained by answering to this riddle?

I am the Apple of this very country.

> The Apple is referred as the fruit from the tree of knowledge, and the solution to riddles over here (this very country) is the knowledge we all desire.

Some sort of politeness we will all share, will we?

> This refers to the "Be Nice" policy of SE sites.

Surprise itself is inferior to me.

> We all want to know the answer, which will surprise us, but reputation is what we seek.

But for you, today, I am mostly irony.

> Isn't it ironic that "reputation" gives you reputation?

---

Hint:

> *Threaten me with your invisible bow and all my secrets I will reveal.*

It's because

> If you put the arrow-shaped cursor on a spoiler, you can see what's hidden.

Comment: The fruit from the tree of knowledge is not an apple. It is referred only to as a fruit.

Comment: @wolfram42 My bad. Linux Blanket is right about the meaning of the Apple. I didn't knew it was never mentioned directly as an apple...

Comment: @wolfram42 I know that it is not an apple, but the Apple has become the idiomatic way of referring to it.

Comment: @LinuxBlanket This is not the answer but you are very close... Now I'm afraid the first part of my riddle was clumsy when I see how close you are ^^ (In fact two of your answers are totaly right ! And I could even say that ironicaly they all are...)

Answer (score 2):

> The New York Times

Because:

> NY is the "big apple"; Exercises civil discourse; Avoids shock-jocks; News and irony go hand in hand

Comment: It may concurs but unfortunately this is not the good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Random guess:

> Surplus

Apple of this very country:

> At least my country (the US) is characterized by massive surplus...  It looks from your network profile like you're from France, where about the same reasoning would apply.  (Or maybe something to do with Apple, Inc., surpluses?)

Some sort of politeness we will all share, will we?

> A surplus of politeness makes things more pleasant for everyone...

Surprise itself is inferior to me.

> In the dictionary I was looking at, "surprise" is essentially the next word after "surplus" (excepting part of speech variants) so "surprise" is *below* "surplus" there.

But for you, today, I am mostly irony.

> Something to do with the daily reputation gain cap on the site?  Maybe expecting somebody already over the cap to get the answer for this one?

So, I admit it's probably a stretch, just wanted to give my thoughts mostly based on the third line.

Comment: Very nice try for the surprise hint. Unfortunately this is not the answer. But you are in a good track for the irony : This is relative to this website. By the way, you are right, I am French but the country I refer is a country we share.

Answer (score 0):

Are You,

> The "answer" of this riddle.

I am the Apple of this very country.

> The fruit of the tree i.e the answer of this question/riddle.

Surprise itself is inferior to me.

> Since it is the "answer" itself, it is greater or superior than the surprise of the answer. This is kind of difficult to explain with words.

But for you, today, I am mostly irony.

> Till we know about it, we are seeking the answer which is "answer" itself. Hence, the irony.

Some sort of politeness we will all share, will we?

> This refers to the "Be Nice" policy of SE sites.

The Hint,

> If you put the arrow-shaped cursor on a spoiler, you can see what's hidden.

Inspired from LinuxBlanket's answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but this not the answer... However, as LinuxBlanket's you aready found the right answer ! :/ You just have to put the pieces together...